# Getting Undefined when assigning Observable inside of map in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I am attempting to understand observables and have run into some frustrations.

I have a `save()` function which calls `initialize()` to get some Id's.   Inside of initialize, I am setting an Observable in a map method (`payload`) and it gets set with the correct values when I log the result to the console.   I have tried switching the map to subscribe to no avail.

**TLDR; What is the proper way to set a value to a pre-hoisted variable from inside of a map/subscribe?**

related:   What is the proper type of observable if you are serializing from an object?

```
save(post: Post, draftId?: number, postId?: number): Observable<any> {
    let payload: Observable<any>;
    if (!postId) {
        post.state = post.state ? post.state : 'unsaved';
        this.initialize(post)
            .subscribe((res) => {  //error here... cannot run 
                console.log('Waypoint: posts.service.ts:36');
                payload = res;
            });

    } else if (draftId && postId) {
        post.state = 'autosaved'
        return this.updateDraft(post, draftId);
    };
    return payload;
}

initialize(post: Post): Observable<any> {
    let resultPost: number;
    let resultDraft: number;
    var payload: Observable<any>;
    this.createPost(post)
        .subscribe(res => {
        resultPost = res.id;
        post.postId = res.id
        this.createDraft(post)
            .map(res => {
                resultDraft = res.id;
                let _payload = {
                    postId: resultPost,
                    draftId: resultDraft
                };
                console.log('Waypoint: posts.service.ts:62');
                payload = Observable.create(_payload); // looks good!
            }, (error) => { console.log(error) }).subscribe();

        });
    console.log(payload); //undefined :(
    return payload;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your logic works more or less like this

1. first you create a **Post** via `createPost` method which returns an
   `Observable`
2. you `subcribe` to `createPost` and you get the result which contains
   the **Post id**
3. you use the **Post id** to create a **Draft** with the method
   `createDraft` which again returns an `Observable`
4. you `subscribe` to `createDraft` and you get as a result the **Draft
   id**
5. then eventually you need to use **Post id** and **Draft id** to fill
   a payload variable which is then used to do something else

Id this is right, what you should probably aim to is something like this

```
let postId;
let draftId;
this.createPost(post)
    .map(res => {postId = res.id})
    .mergeMap(() => this.createDraft(post))  // mergeMap is same as flatMap
    .map(res => {draftId = res.id})
    .map(() => [postId, draftId])
    .subscribe(postDraftIds => payload = postDraftIds)
```

There are other ways of using the Observable operators to reach the same goal (e.g. you could use switchMap rather than mergeMap - here a very good link that explains [how switchMap works](http://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-switchmap-operator/)), but I hope this is clear enough

Answer (score 1):

To answer some of your questions:

1. console.log(payload); is undefined probable, because this line of code is executed before the subscribe on this.createDraft takes place
2. You are using way too much subscribe's, there should be only one, in the place where actually you want to receive the data, in previous cases you can user for example `map/flatMap` operator. Using proper operators can significantly reduce the code complexity like:

   ```
   save(post: Post, draftId?: number, postId?: number): Observable<Payload> {
       if (!postId) {
           post.state = post.state ? post.state : 'unsaved';
           return this.initialize(post);
       } else if (draftId && postId) {
           post.state = 'autosaved'
           return this.updateDraft(post, draftId);
       }

       return Observable.empty(); 
   }

   initialize(post: Post): Observable<Payload> {
       let resultPost: number;
       return this.createPost(post)
           .flatMap(res => {
               resultPost = res.id;
               post.postId = res.id;
               return this.createDraft(post)
           }.map(res =>  new Payload(resultPost, res.id));
   }}
   ```

export class Payload {
    postId: number;
    draftId: number;

```
constructor(postId: number, draftId: number) {
    this.postId = postId;
    this.draftId = draftId;
}
```

}

in fact the `initialize` could be refactored even more to something like:

```
 initialize(post: Post): Observable<Payload> {
        return this.createPost(post)
            .flatMap(res => {
                return Observable.zip(res.id, this.createDraft(post))
            }).map(res =>  new Payload(res[0], res[1].id));
    }
```

3. Do not use `any`, use specific types instead

note: I did not run this code, I simply advice you to play with the operators

// do not know why Payload is not rendered properly ...